# Array Check if key not exist add default value

Tags: php, arrays

```
$list = Array
    (
        [Jul] => Array
            (
                [deposit] => Array
                    (
                        [totalcount] => 1
                        [totalamount] => 12
                    )
    
            )
    
        [Oct] => Array
            (
            )
    
        [Nov] => Array
            (
            )
    
        [Dec] => Array
            (
                [deposit] => Array
                    (
                        [totalcount] => 2
                        [totalamount] => 2400
                    )
    
                [withdraw] => Array
                    (
                        [totalcount] => 1
                        [totalamount] => 3000
                    )
    
            )
 
    )
```

**//my code**

```
foreach ($list as $ekey => $evalue) {
            if(!array_column($list[$ekey], 'deposit')){
                $list[$ekey]['deposit'] = array(
                                        'totalcount'  => 0,
                                        'totalamount' => 0
                                    );
            }else if(!array_column($list[$ekey], 'withdraw')){
                $list[$ekey]['withdraw'] = array(
                                        'totalcount'  => 0,
                                        'totalamount' => 0
                                    );
            }
        }
```

**Question:** Above code is to check whether the data inside each array have the same key, does it mean that every key in the array should have the **"deposit"** and **"withdraw"**. If not found it will assign the default value to it. But my code will only insert deposit value into those missing, it will not insert withdraw value into it? Anyone can help with this :(??

Comment: Use `if` instead of `else if` on line 7

Comment: To expands on @Lessmore's comment, the `elseif` branch will only be entered if the first condition is not met. So your code didn't cover the case when both `deposit` and `withdraw` were missing. Since these are independent, you need two independent conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier just to merge the existing values into the defaults:

```
$default = array('deposit'  => array('totalcount'  => 0, 'totalamount' => 0),
                 'withdraw' => array('totalcount'  => 0, 'totalamount' => 0));

foreach ($list as &$evalue) {
    $evalue = array_merge($default, $evalue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This option creates a template array with the keys from your original list and empty values.  Then it uses `array_replace_recursive()` to overwrite any existing values from the start list into the template array...

```
$template = array_fill_keys(array_keys($list), [
        "deposit" => ["totalcount" => 0,"totalamount" => 0],
        "withdraw" => ["totalcount" => 0,"totalamount" => 0]
]);
$list = array_replace_recursive($template, $list);
```